# Does Pirelli have a motorcycle tire warranty?

Tags: motorcycle, tires, warranty

I can't find any information about a motorcycle tire warranty for Pirelli. Does anyone know if Pirelli offers a warranty on their motorcycle tires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy paste from the Pirelli USA website:

> PIRELLI ORIGINAL EQUIPMENT & REPLACEMENT LIMITED WARRANTY MOTORCYCLE
>   TIRES
>
> What Is Warranted and Who Is Eligible Under the Warranty?
>
> Pirelli Tire LLC (Pirelli), 100 Pirelli Drive, PO Box 700, Rome, GA
>   30161-7000, warrants to the original purchaser that all Pirelli
>   Original Equipment and Replacement Motorcycle tires with a complete
>   D.O.T. identification number and branded Pirelli, which are supplied
>   by Pirelli, either directly or through an authorized Dealer, and which
>   are mounted on motorcycles within the U.S.A. and Canada will be free
>   from defects in workmanship and materials. The Pirelli Original
>   Equipment & Replacement Limited Warranty is subject to periodic
>   revision; see the Warranty section at www.us.pirelli.com for the
>   latest version.
>
> If further assistance or information is needed regarding Pirelli tires
>   please contact:
>
> Pirelli Tire LLC  Consumer Affairs Group  Monday through Friday  8:00
>   AM to 6:00 PM Eastern Standard Time  1-800-747-3554, option 2 Warranty
>   Basics
>
> Tire Registration
>
> Please request your dealer to register your replacement tires, provide
>   you with a registration card, or go to www.us.Pirelli.com to register
>   your tires on line. In case of a tire recall, we can reach you only if
>   we have your name and address. You must register your tires to be on
>   our list.
>
> What Is the Adjustment Policy and For How Long?
>
> Pirelli motorcycle tires are covered by this warranty for the duration
>   of the tire life as defined below. For street tires, the tire life is
>   defined by the tread area of the tire having a tread depth of 1/32” (1
>   mm) or more.  For Off road and Motocross, the tire life is defined by
>   the tread area of the tire having a remaining tread depth of at least
>   20% of the original new tread depth. This warranty is extended to the
>   first retail purchaser of the tire(s) in the U.S.A and Canada with the
>   original purchase invoice or to the original owner of the motorcycle
>   on which Pirelli tires came mounted as Original Equipment.
>
> If a Pirelli tire becomes unserviceable due to workmanship or material
>   anomalies during its normal service life and within the first 50% of
>   tread life, the tire will be replaced with the same or comparable tire
>   at no charge to the owner*. If a Pirelli tire becomes unserviceable
>   due to workmanship or material anomalies after the first 50% of tread
>   life, the owner must pay the cost for a comparable new Pirelli brand
>   tire at a value of 50% of the dealer selling price*.
>
> Ride related warranty claims must be submitted within the first 2/32”
>   (1.6 mm) of wear or the first 1000 miles to be considered.  If
>   accepted they will be paid at 100% of the dealer selling price*.
>
> *Note: This Limited Warranty does not cover any associated service charges, including costs associated with mounting and balancing of the
>   tire.
>
> A tire has delivered its original usable tread life and is considered
>   to be 100% worn when the treadwear indicators (1/32” tread remaining)
>   become visible, regardless of age or mileage.
>
> What Is Not Covered by the Limited Warranty?
>
> Tires on any motorcycle registered and normally operated outside the United States of America or Canada
>   Tires which are misapplied due to insufficient Speed Rating, or Load Index, or undersized or oversized tires.
>   Tires which are misapplied due to improper mixing of radial and bias tires
>   Tires damaged from improper mounting/demounting practices, abuse, misuse, or neglect
>   Tire dealer / retailer services: mounting, dismounting, and balancing costs
>   Tires in which anything other than air or nitrogen has been used as the support medium
>   Tires injected with liquid balancer or sealant or any other balancing material.
>   Tires which have been modified by the addition or removal of material or any tire intentionally altered to change its appearance
>   Tires which have been retreaded or regrooved
>   Tires used in any form of racing or any high performance riding events including high performance riding schools/instruction and track day events
>   Tires removed as a pair when only one tire can be claimed, or is suspect of a claim
>   Ride related anomalies after the first 2/32” (1.6 mm) of treadwear 
>   Tires which become unserviceable because of tire operation in excess of tire/wheel manufacturers’ specifications and recommendations, including spinning
>   Tires which become unserviceable because of a mechanical irregularity in the motorcycle such as misalignment, defective brakes, defective suspension parts or improper rims
>   Tires damaged by fire, chemical corrosion, vandalism, wrecks, theft, run while flat, underinflated, overinflated or abused during servicing
>   Tires affected by flat spotting caused by improper transport or storage
>   Tires which become unserviceable because of road hazard injuries (e.g., nails, glass, metal objects) or other penetrations or snags, bruises or impact damage
>   Tires which have been run on a dynamometer
>   Tires worn 100%, which is when any treadwear indicator (1/32” tread remaining) become visible regardless of age or mileage
>   Tires which develop surface cracks due to use in low ambient temperatures, except for race tires 
>   Labor to install a replacement tire
>   Claims for irregular wear or fast wear
>   Tires used on a vehicle towing a trailer
>
> Owner’s Responsibilities
>
> The owner/rider is responsible for proper tire care and maintenance.
>   Maintain the correct tire pressure recommended by frequently checking
>   the tire pressure with an accurate pressure gauge.  Using Pirelli’s
>   pressure suggestions based on load will improve tire life and your
>   satisfaction with the tires.
>
> CAUTION:
>
> Please be aware that it is important to ensure that, before fitting
>   the suggested tires, the fitting is allowed by the technical
>   specifications of the motorcycle, the motorcycle manufacturer and the
>   relevant homologations. Pirelli does not express any view as to the
>   compatibility of the wheel/tire combination with the technical
>   specifications for the chassis and motorcycle.
>
> ​TO MAINTAIN MOTORCYCLE DYNAMICS AND LOAD CARRYING CAPACITY,
>   REPLACEMENT TIRES MUST ALWAYS HAVE A LOAD INDEX AND SPEED RATING THAT
>   EQUALS OR EXCEEDS THAT OF THE ORIGINAL EQUIPMENT TIRES OF THE
>   MOTORCYCLE. How to Make a Claim under This Warranty
>
> Owner: To receive consideration for warranty coverage, tire(s) must be
>   returned to any Pirelli authorized dealer. Tire Inspection Personnel
>   designated by Pirelli make the final determination regarding
>   qualification for Workmanship and Materials coverage on tires
>   submitted to Pirelli via an authorized Pirelli dealer.Pirelli’s Tire
>   Inspection Personnel will then make a determination regarding
>   qualification for Workmanship and Materials coverage on tires.
>
> ​When making a claim under the terms of this warranty, you must
>   present the tire along with the proof of purchase to any authorized
>   Pirelli Dealer. Once tires are returned to Pirelli by an authorized
>   Pirelli dealer and credit has been issued, submitted tires become the
>   property of Pirelli. To locate an authorized Pirelli Dealer in your
>   area, refer to the Dealer Locator at www.us.Pirelli.com. Replacement
>   Costs
>
> If a Pirelli tire is found to have a warrantable condition, and has
>   50% or more of its original tread depth remaining, the consumer will
>   be eligible for a 100% credit toward the purchase of a new Pirelli
>   tire.
>
> If a Pirelli tire is found to have a warrantable condition, and has
>   less than 50% of its original tread depth remaining, but has not reach
>   the treadwear indicators, the consumer will be eligible for a 50%
>   credit toward the purchase of a new Pirelli tire.
>
> THIS LIMITED WARRANTY IS THE ONLY EXPRESS WARRANTY GIVEN BY PIRELLI. 
>   PIRELLI DOES NOT MAKE ANY OTHER EXPRESS WARRANTY, INCLUDING WITHOUT
>   LIMITATION THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE (WHICH ARE EXPRESSLY DISCLAIMED).  PIRELLI DOES NOT
>   AUTHORIZE ANY OTHER PERSON, INCLUDING AUTHORIZED PIRELLI DEALERS OR
>   MOTORCYCLE MANUFACTURERS, OR MOTOCYCLE DEALERS, TO CHANGE THIS
>   WARRANTY OR CREATE ANY OTHER OBLIGATION IN CONNECTION WITH PIRELLI
>   TIRES.
>
> THE RIGHTS AND REMEDIES AVAILABLE ARE LIMITED TO THOSE RIGHTS AND
>   REMEDIES STATED IN THIS LIMITED WARRANTY.  ALL OTHER REMEDIES ARE
>   EXCLUDED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL PIRELLI BE RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY
>   CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR SPECIAL DAMAGE(S) IN CONNECTION WITH A
>   PIRELLI TIRE, WHETHER FOR BREACH OF THIS LIMITED WARRANTY, OTHER
>   CONTRACT BREACH, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORT, OR STRICT LIABILITY THEORY.
>
> ​Some states do not allow the exclusion or limitation of incidental or
>   consequential damages, so the above exclusion may not apply to you.
>   This warranty gives you specific legal rights and you may also have
>   other rights which vary from state to state.